# How to check if filenames in specific folder are inside database table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Start situation:

- a folder with lots of files (images mostly `png`).
- two tables in database (MariaDB) which contains supposed image filenames. I query the filenames like this:

```
select filename from table1 
UNION 
select filename from table2;
```

I want to know if I have files not registered in the database tables.

- My first approach is to put the list of filenames inside a textfile (I've used Linux command line, list is filename per line), but I don't know how to continue.
- <strike>I can't write in the database.</strike> UPDATED. **I got more auth to perform my job tasks. Therefore I solved this with the suggestion.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do couple of things:

- Import the file with list of files into the database.
- Use cursor to go through the list of file names and match it to your table list which contains the list-b of file names

To import file name you can use the import method or directly read the file as a table virtually.

Thanks

Comment: Well, not a programming solution but thanks for your time. If i'm about to use the list of filenames my best bet is to ask to my db the access to make a convinient table to solve it on a sql query